# Ruby read CSV file using gets

Tags: ruby

I dont know if its possible but here is what i'm trying achieve:

```
Please enter file path to analyse your expenses :
user enters statment.csv
and programs reads data.
```

my code :

```
require 'csv'

puts "Please enter file path to analize"
  file = gets
data = CSV.read(file, headers: true)
>
>
>
```

so far got messages that file couldn't be found.
All files are in same Folder. 
Desktop/expenses_calculator

E

Comment: `pp` is your friend when debugging Ruby programs. Try `require 'pp'` and then `pp file` to see what `file` contains after you've read it with `gets`. You will see the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What's the value of `file` after you type something?

```
puts 'Please enter file path to analize'
file = gets
p file
# => "some_file.csv\n"
```

Most probably you want to add [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) which *"returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of the string (if present)."*

You could try with something like:

```
puts 'Please enter file path to analize'
file = gets.chomp
data = CSV.read(file, headers: true)
```